# MongoDB sharding is possible on collections?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Can is it possible sharding only on collections ? if yes than how..?
What is difference between sharding on database and on collections?

Comment: Mongo **only shards by collection** (at this stage). See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/#sharding-in-mongodb).

Comment: This question is off topic on Stackoverflow, which is aimed at programming questions. It would be more suited on http://dba.stackoverflow.com. One piece of advice, though: Sharding seems simple. It isn't. The intricacies can get _pretty_ complicated. You might want to have a _very deep_ look at the documentation and probably http://university.mongodb.com before proceeding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongodb shards collections. You enable sharding on database but just enabling sharding on database will not distribute data across shards. To distribute data accross shards you need to tell mongodb what collection to distribute. So, you have to shard your collection and then only that collection will be spread across the shards.

Remember, mongodb will distribute data on the basis of collections sharded. If you have 2 collections in your database and you shard one of them then data of sharded collection will be spread out across the shards but the other collection will have all data on one shard.

In plain language, mongodb doesn't shard whole database automatically. Mongodb sharding works on collection level.